# Kotlin - creating a mutable list with repeating elements

Tags: list, kotlin

What would be an idiomatic way to create a mutable list of a given length `n` with repeating elements of value `v` (e.g `listOf(4,4,4,4,4)`) as an expression.

I'm doing `val list = listOf((0..n-1)).flatten().map{v}` but it can only create an immutable list.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Use:

```
val list = MutableList(n) {index -> v}
```

or, since `index` is unused, you could omit it:

```
val list = MutableList(n) { v }
```

Comment: Additionally, since `index` is unused, you could omit it: `val list = MutableList(n) { v }`

Comment: Thanks! The same for immutable list: `val list = List(n) { SomeClass }`.

Comment: Simply using `List` is an option if mutability is unneeded, so `val list = List(n) { v }`

Answer (score 35):

another way may be:

```
val list = generateSequence { v }.take(4).toMutableList()
```

This style is compatible with both MutableList and (Read Only) List

Comment: Be careful with using this if `v` is a mutable sequence because the generated `list` will still have a reference to `v`, so if somewhere else one does `v[1] = 3`, the contents of `list` will also change.

Answer (score 10):

If you want different objects you can use `repeat`.
For example,

```
 val list = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
   repeat(2){ this.add(element = "YourObject($it)") }
 }
```

Replace String with your object. Replace 2 with number of elements you want.

Comment: I got "Index out of bounds" on  `index = it-1`. You can just remove that since it is anyway not required to specify the index when adding to a list.

Answer (score 10):

You're able to use the **ranges** for this purpose, e.g.

```
        val listOfFour = (1..10).map { 4 }
```

or

```
        val objectList = (1..10).map {
            YourClass(
                arg1 = "someValue",
                arg2 = it                
            )
        }
```

if you need you can use `it` (index) for your needs as well.